# jQuery Selector with *Only* a Pound/Hash Character $('#')

Tags: jquery

I'm porting a bunch of jQuery scripts to plain Javascript, and came across this:

`$('#').attr['target', '_blank');`

It appears to be manipulating an anchor tag, but what does it actually select?  An empty id attribute (`<a id=""></a>`)?  Is it just malformed?

(Most search engines don't seem to like queries with no alphanumeric text, and searches like "jQuery pound/hash selector" mostly just explain jQuery id selection.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that code will do is throw an internal jQuery selector syntax error since there is nothing after the `#` id prefix

```js
try {
  $('#').attr('target', '_blank')
} catch ({message}) {
  console.log(`Caught error: "${message}"`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id=""></a>
```